# What are the principles of the Ruby parser?

Tags: ruby, parsing, lexical-analysis, lexical-scope

How can I predict how Ruby will parse things?

I came across a really surprising parsing error in Ruby while trying to concatenate strings.

```
> "every".capitalize +"thing"
=> NoMethodError: undefined method `+@' for "thing":String
```

Of course, if you put the extra space in their, it works as intended;

```
> "every".capitalize + "thing"
=> "Everything"
```

This error will occur if I have `anything.any_method +"any string"`. What Ruby does is assume that we have elided parentheses, and are trying to give an argument to the method;

```
"every".capitalize( +"thing" )
```

It notices that we haven't defined the unary operator `+@` on strings, and throws that error.

My question is, what principles should I use to predict the behavior of the Ruby parser? I only figured this error out after a lot of googling. It's notable that `.capitalize` takes no parameters ever (not even in the C source code). If you use a method that doesn't apply to the previous object, it still throws the `+@` error instead of a `undefined method 'capitalize' for "every":String` error. So this parsing is obviously high-level. I'm not knowledgeable enough to read through Matz's [parser.y](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/parse.y). I've come across other similarly surprising errors. Can anyone tell me Ruby's parsing priority?

Comment: There is the [Ruby grammar](http://web.njit.edu/all_topics/Prog_Lang_Docs/html/ruby/yacc.html) in BNF form as well, that is a little less dense than the parser.y file.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to see how ruby is parsing your code, you can dump the parsetree, i.e.

`ruby -e '"every".capitalize +"thing"' --dump parsetree`

```
# @ NODE_SCOPE (line: 1)
# +- nd_tbl: (empty)
# +- nd_args:
# |   (null node)
# +- nd_body:
#     @ NODE_CALL (line: 1)
#     +- nd_mid: :capitalize
#     +- nd_recv:
#     |   @ NODE_STR (line: 1)
#     |   +- nd_lit: "every"
#     +- nd_args:
#         @ NODE_ARRAY (line: 1)
#         +- nd_alen: 1
#         +- nd_head:
#         |   @ NODE_CALL (line: 1)
#         |   +- nd_mid: :+@
#         |   +- nd_recv:
#         |   |   @ NODE_STR (line: 1)
#         |   |   +- nd_lit: "thing"
#         |   +- nd_args:
#         |       (null node)
#         +- nd_next:
#             (null node)
```

I like to use [explainruby](http://explainruby.net/) sometimes too, cause it's much easier on my eyes :)